# how to random one result from mysql results by using one sql

Tags: mysql, select

I use mysql select some data for player. and the result is a list while I just want a random one.
the following sql is syntax error after limit 1

```sql
select * from tb_rank where score<=150 and score>= 50 and power>=80 and power<=120
limit 1,(select round(rand()*(select count(*) as num from tb_rank where score<=150 and score>= 50 and power>=80 and power<=120)))
```

Comment: You might want to explain this with an example, it's really hard to understand your explanation.

Comment: How is this question related to Lua?

Comment: Hi,I want to an algorithm by lua

Comment: So you want to select all players whose score is within 50 points of your score, and whose power is between 80% and 120% of yours? You should be able to do that in a single scan of the players' list. You shouldn't need to use `BucketPile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50.000 people are a lot if you have them in front of you. But you are talking about crunching numbers on a computer. Here 50.000 is nothing.

Sorting would just take additional time and it is not necessary as you want a random player that has your score ±50 and your power ±20%. A random player of a sorted list is still a random player. It wouldn't make any difference.

Iterate over your playerlist, build a new list of players that have a valid score and power. Then pick a random element of that new list.

On my average laptop this takes less than 5 microsconds.

Comment: Hi，I must sort my playerlist, because everyone has a rank.
Rank is calculated according to the score.

Comment: @张浩杰 in your question you said that you wanted a list of players that have your score ±50 and 100±20% of your power. from that list you wanted to pick a random player. if you pick a random player sorting the list doesn't make any sense...